# Pointer Value in Struct Changing Without Reassigning

Tags: c, pointers, x86, gdb

I'm getting the following output from gdb:

```
(gdb) print tid->rvm
$28 = (rvm_t) 0x605010
(gdb) step
306     rlog->entries[i].sizes[num - 1] = size;
(gdb) step
307 }
(gdb) print tid->rvm
$29 = (rvm_t) 0x64
(gdb) print tid
$30 = (trans_t) 0x607b50
```

This is the code for the tid structure:

```
struct _trans_t {
    rvm_t rvm;          
    int numsegs;       
    segment_t* segments;
};
```

The rvm_t rvm is a struct containing metadata for a recoverable virtual memory pager.

I don't believe I am allowed to post the full function code where this is happening, because this is a university assignment, but you can see the single line of code where this change occurs, `rlog->entries[i].sizes[num - 1] = size;`. There is no reference to the value that get changed. I also have to use this ugly typedefing pointers to structs thing. The assignment submission server contains the header file as-is and I can't edit it.

My question is what the heck can cause this. tid is passed as a parameter to a function `rvm_about_to_modify(trans_t tid, void *segbase, int offset, int size)`. The struct member rvm is never touched inside this function and you can see the step sequence where it has address 0x605010, which is the correct address, and one line later, without any reference
to either the tid struct or its rvm member, the pointer changes to address 0x64. The actual tid pointer has not changed. It keeps address 0x607b50 throughout.

I'm complete at a loss here and can't figure out what would cause tid->rvm to change value without ever being touched. From what I can tell, 0x64 is the address of the interrupt vector table entry for the keyboard status register. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Here's some requested updates. The value of i is 0, the value of num is 1, the value of rlog is 0x607b30. rlog->entries[0] is an entry for changes to a data segment with name "testseg", size 10000 bytes, updatesize 300 bytes, numupdates 1, and pointers to arrays of offsets, sizes, and data. rlog->entries[0].sizes[0] is 100. The data pointer is 0x6051f0.

Comment: you should at least provide the following (from within gdb): value of i, value of num, address of rlog->entries[i].sizes[num-1], address of tid. This might give you some hints on what's happening, already.

Comment: "*Pointer Value in Struct Changing Without Reassigning*" this strongly smells like memory corruption. I propose you run the program using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: See my answer, alk. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot post the full code, we cannot explain in any detail.  However, your assertion that "tid->rvm [changes] value without ever being touched" is self-contradictory.  What you can say is that structure member `tid->rvm` is not changed *via structure pointer `tid`*, *by the thread being debugged*.

Supposing that the structure does not live in shared memory and that the process is single-threaded, the only possible conclusion is that `tid->rvm`
is fully or partially aliased by `rlog->entries[i].sizes[num - 1]`.  That is, the memory to which the left-hand side of the second expression refers overlaps that to which the first refers.  There are several ways that could happen, among them:

- the `tid` and/or `rlog` pointer points to the wrong place
- the current value of `i` is outside the bounds of array `rlog->entries`
- the expression `num - 1` is outside the bounds of array `rlog->entries[i].sizes`

Those are by no means the only possibilities, but they are the most likely ones among those that can be guessed from the limited amount of code presented.

Comment: It's a single threaded child process forked from a parent that waits for it to complete before resuming execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. valgrind helped. Turns out I wasn't initializing some of the pointers in the rlog->entries elements, so when I wrote to them later, it spilled into addresses allocated previously to tid->rvm and overwrote it. Still not sure why an invalidated pointer is redirected to the keyboard status register.